# I can access to elementaryOs files from outside and/or how to crypt the home folder

Tags: encryption, home, accessibility

I need to hide my files, but from another Linux partition or linuxLive I can access to the files in the home folder. I don't want this.
I also tried to set reading right off with chmode but anyone can still access to y files.

Or why crypting the home folder is not possible in ElementaryOs ?

Reagrds